# SQL Server Stored Procedure Data Type Conversion in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that does what I expect it to do in SQL returning the data for any year period I enter, but I am having difficulty binding the stored procedure to an Excel Spreadsheet which won't allow me to do so due to an error it's returning when trying to convert varchar to int. It's a relatively small piece of SQL but essentially I want to bind the `@Year` parameter to an Excel cell for an end user.

It states *"Error converting data type varchar to tinyint"* in Excel. Any help is much welcomed. Below is the stored procedure.

My definition string in Excel:

> EXECUTE dbo.StoredProcedure 'Year'

The stored procedure:

```
@Year Tinyint
AS 

SELECT DBO.users.loginname,
       Cast(Datename(M, DBO.contractdate.contractdate) AS VARCHAR) AS DatePeriod,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN DBO.contract.contract = 1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END)                                                    AS Contract,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN DBO.contract.contract = 0 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END)                                                    AS Permanant
FROM   DBO.contractskill
       INNER JOIN DBO.users
                  INNER JOIN DBO.contract
                          ON DBO.users.userid = DBO.contract.userid
                  INNER JOIN DBO.contractdate
                          ON DBO.contract.contractid = DBO.contractdate.contractid
               ON DBO.contractskill.contractid = DBO.contract.contractid
WHERE  ( DBO.contractdate.dns = 0 )
       AND ( DBO.contractskill.skillid = 30960 )
       AND Year(DBO.contractdate.contractdate) = @Year
GROUP  BY Cast(Datename(M, DBO.contractdate.contractdate) AS VARCHAR),
          Month(DBO.contractdate.contractdate),
          DBO.users.loginname
ORDER  BY Month(DBO.contractdate.contractdate)
```

Comment: The problem is when you call your procedure. You are passing a string literal 'Year' and the datatype expected is tinyint. It will attempt an implicit conversion which will of course fail. The next challenge is your decision to use tinyint. The largest value for a tinyint in 255 and I doubt that most of your contracts are from ancient roman times. Perhaps a more appropriate datatype here would be smallint.

Comment: And the sql posted is not even close to valid. You have joins with no predicates, multiple ON clauses for some of your joins. You really should get in the habit of using aliases to simplify your code a lot.

Comment: @SeanLange I reformatted a bit, maybe now it's more clear.

Comment: @TT the query is more clear but it still has lots of syntax errors. Maybe the OP will come back around and try to clarify some of this.

Comment: Hi, apologies for the unclarity of the syntax and thanks for reformatting this, I am using a smallint for Year parameter now. 

What i am trying to achieve is passing @year as a parameter into a cell in an Excel Spreadsheet which I have linked my stored procedure to. 

This would be in the format of '2015' or '2014' for example, the query works in SQL but not in Excel as Sean suggests it is failing at conversion, however I am not sure how i can work around this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any ideas guys?